# List of Nobel laureates classified by majors

Tags: nobel-prize, big-list

I have been looking for a list of Nobel laureates classified by their majors, e.g., electrical engineering, mechanical engineering, etc. Since some of them may have changed the major from master course or doctor course, it would be preferable that the list is listed with all majors in BSc, MSc, DSc.

Given my current lack of Google-ability, I've been unable to found it. Should I have to know it checking each of the laureates by Wikipedia?

At least I want to know the laureates who have got degrees in electrical engineering or kind of like that.

Answer (score 2):

Google gives:

> Jack St. Clair Kilby, a 1950 masters degree graduate in electrical engineering at the University of Wisconsin–Madison, has been named a co-winner of the 2000 Nobel Prize in physics.

Answer (score 1):

Paul Dirac is a well known physics Nobel laureate for his work in the foundations of quantum mechanics (in 1933 alongside Erwin Schrödinger and Werner Heisenberg). His biography in the Nobel foundation reads [[1]](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1933/dirac/biographical/):

> Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac was born on 8th August, 1902, at Bristol, England, his father being Swiss and his mother English. He was educated at the Merchant Venturer’s Secondary School, Bristol, then went on to Bristol University. Here, he studied electrical engineering, obtaining the B.Sc. (Engineering) degree in 1921.